# Can iText be used to generate dynamic tagged pdfs on the fly

Tags: pdf, dynamic, accessibility, section508

I have checked the itext archives and was unable to find an answer.  I am a novice doing research to find out if iText can be used to create Sec. 508 compliant tagged PDFs that would be generated dynamically on demand in real time using data streams merged with templates to output a PDF.  Generating 600K pages per day of customized documents.

I just need to know where I can find the explanation of how to do this and how it would work not necessarily the code itself.  Trying to retrofit a legacy application to be Section 508 compliant and trying to find a software solution.  Any information is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We have the same requirements, lots of dynamically generated PDFs.  We merge compliant PDFs and iText strips out the tags for us.

Last year, I researched this issue, and at the time, tag preservation, could not be done.

PDFBox 
    [ https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-1342?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel ]

and iText have had some recent rumblings of addressing this issue.